# Finding the local extrema of $y = \frac{\ln x} {\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I'm given a function: $$y = \frac{\ln x} {\sqrt{x}}$$

I've found the first derivative, which is
$$y' = \frac{2-\ln(x)}{2x\sqrt(x)}$$
and got that the domain is $x > 0$, but I just don't know how to find maxima/minima when I have a natural logarithm.

Comment: You need to find the critical points, i.e. where derivative is zero. Why is log relevant here? $ln(x)-2=0 \implies x=e^2$  which is ≈7.3 Now just check it's maxima or minima by second derivative test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>0$,

As you found
$$f'(x)=\frac{2-\ln(x)}{2x\sqrt{x}}$$

the deniminator is $>0$, the sign of $ f'(x) $ is given by the sign of the numerator $ 2-\ln(x) $.

$$f'(x)=0\iff \ln(x)=2$$
$$\iff x=e^2$$

$$f'(x)>0\iff 2>\ln(x)$$
$$\iff 0<x<e^2$$

thus $ f $ is increasing at $  (0,e^2] $ and decreasing at $ [e^2,+\infty)$.

$ f $ attains its maximum at $ x=e^2$.
on the other hand
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=-\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$$
So, it has no minimum.